# `popperManager is undefined` when trying to use reactstrap DropdownMenu

Tags: reactjs, next.js, reactstrap, popper.js

`reactstrap` seems to be working fine with components that don't use popper, but when I try to use DropdownToggle and DropdownMenu I get `popperManager is undefined`. I'm using `nextjs`, but not sure if that's relevant. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what happens when you forget to wrap `DropdownToggle` and `DropdownMenu` elements in a `Dropdown` element.